# Loading R.U.B.E JSON file into Box2D

Tags: java, json, libgdx, box2d, jbox2d

I am really interested in using the R.U.B.E editor to create my own players and what not. I am getting accustomed to Box2D through the use of LibGDX. But i can not find any resources (tutorials or examples) on how to load the JSON file into the Box2D world and use it. Please point me into some direction! I am really excited to study and learn this but have no clue where to find how to do it. I don't mind if its not Java, it can be c++. Sorry for my mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two R.U.B.E. loaders for libgdx:

- https://github.com/tescott/RubeLoader
- https://github.com/cvayer/gdx-rube

I have used both of them and they work pretty well. I prefer the first one though. I think one of them is a fork of the other. Both of them have an `AssetLoader` which takes a .json file and returns a Box2D `World`.